# How do i link manufacturer with categories in magento

Tags: magento

I would like to link the categories and manufacturers of products in my magento website.My goal is to achieve a drop down like

**<< Select Categories >>** (list of available categories, i want to load manufacturers after user selects manufacturer) 
  **<< Select Manufacturer >>**

i can create a custom module to fetch values, but dont know how to link categories and manufacturers? can anybody help me a hand on this.?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following articles.

**Layered Navigation**

> When a customer is browsing through
>   your site they need to find the
>   products that interest them as fast as
>   possible or you won’t make the sale.
>   And when confronted with a category
>   containing 60 products spread across
>   multiple pages most customers will
>   simply throw in the towel. Give them
>   the option to filter by what interests
>   them though, whether it’s price,
>   manufacturer or any other aspect of
>   the products, and you can show your
>   customers what they want and raise
>   conversions.

[How does Layered Navigation work?](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-does-layered-navigation-work/)

[Change layered navigation - Define any attribute to display in layered navigation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/5500/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use "Manufactures" attribute as layered navigation filter and then it is handled by Magento layered navigation filters block

Comment: can you pls brief me out the steps to be done..? or any links to these steps would be helpful....!!

Comment: i believe that manufacturer attribute is filterable by default , you can check it under products > attributes